# Why do I get datetime conversion out of range for 999 milliseconds?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2017

Could someone please explain me, why I get the error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

when I execute the following code on SQL Server 2017. I get the error only for .999 milliseconds

```
SELECT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME)
```

Result:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Then I tried:

```
SELECT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.998' AS DATETIME)
```

Result: 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997

Then I tried:

```
SELECT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.997' AS DATETIME)
```

Result: 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997

Comment: As states in my Question, SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on documentation the datetime range is between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999. Also still based on documentation the time range is between 00 to 23:59:997.

So if you make a rounding, at 998 it will round down to 997. At 999 it should round up to January 01 10000 which is out of range. (the precision of datetime in sql-server is 3.33ms)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you think of a reason for this?

Comment: It's all about the precision. SQL Server does not have the precision at 1ms but at 3.33. That means that it needs to round up or down based on where you are with your datetime. It uses normal conversion rules.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime (did I mean always ?) reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) helps a lot.

It states :

> Date range : January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999
>
> Time range : 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997

Concerning the time being valid for `23:59:59.998`, even if the valid range is up to `997` ms, this is still explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision)

Times from `23:59:59.995` to `23:59:59.998` are stored as `23:59:59.997`

Time `23:59:59.999` is stored as `00:00:00.000` **+1 day**

Then, `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999` is stored as `10000-01-01 00:00:00.000` which is **out of range**

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` is only accurate to 1/300 of a second, therefore it only shows times that are accurate to .000, .003 and .007 of a second (the last is 2 thirds of a second rounded to  3 decimal places).

For your value `'9999-12-31 23:59:59.999'` SQL server can't store the 0.009, so it rounds to the closest value, in this case that would be the next second, making the date `'10000-12-31 00:00:00.000'`, which can't be stored in any of the date and time data types.

When you have `.998` the closest value to round to is `.997`, so the error does not occur.

If you use a `datetime2` you won't receive the error either, as that can be accurate to 1/10000000 of as second: `SELECT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.999' AS datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the hundred of second are rounded like this :

- 999 -> 000 rounded up (which cause your error)
- 998, 997, 996, 995 -> 997
- 992, 993, 994 -> 993
- 991, 990 -> 990

This is because the datetime data type is not precise enough to store those values. You can use datetime2 if you need more precision.

If you like to understand how the datetime is stored in SQL Server, I recommend this article : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/